# Where to put robots.txt file?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, robots.txt

Where should put robots.txt?

```
domainname.com/robots.txt
```

or

```
domainname/public_html/robots.txt
```

I placed the file in `domainname.com/robots.txt`, but it's not opening when I type this in browser.

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/358900/11056202047-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/358900/11056202047-My-Desktop.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Where the file goes in your filesystem depends on what host you're using, so it's hard for us to give a specific answer about that.

The best description is: put it wherever the `index.html` (or `index.php` or whatever) file is that represents your homepage. If that's `domainname/public_html/index.html`, for example, put it in `domainname/public_html/robots.txt`.

Comment: thanks it's working now i placed at domainname/public_html/index.html

Comment: That's not correct. It has to be in the root directory of the web server, which is different if your home page is in a subdirectory.

Comment: By "homepage" here I mean the proper homepage for the domain. Some robots will also read `robots.txt` files from subdirectories, but that's not as reliable as "the" robots.txt at a website's root.

Comment: I followed your answer but I cannot access it yet. My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302465/i-cannot-access-robots-txt-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 2):

i think the better way to describe it is to have it in the root web folder of your domain... so `http://example.com/robots.txt`  you can also put your sitemap.xml in the root or refer to it with a `Sitemap: http://example.com/fldr/smap.xml` line in your robots.txt.

**dont forget:** you can use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to check to make sure you haven't restricted anything you didnt mean to(you also get to see queries and links woohoo!).

**suggestion:** id consider using the `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">` if possible because you will still earn linkjuice for links on the page but it wont show up in googles index while a robots.txt directive can leave a plain url with do description in SERPs but will loose all value of links pointed to it because its robots.txted out (its ranking b/c of anchor text so get credit for it)

Answer (score 2):

In the root of your web directory (where you put the files that show up on your website)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should put it in `domainname/public_html/robots.txt`, as the `public.html` folder is where your index file will be.